# Checking for password strength

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

Can anyone tell me on what's wrong here in the password field `validation`.I am checking for password `strength`, regardless of what ever i enter it always says "**password must contain atleast one number and one character**"

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("pwcheck", function(value) {
   return /^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]$/.test(value) // consists of only these
       && /[a-z]/.test(value) // has a lowercase letter
       && /\d/.test(value) // has a digit
}, "password must contain atleast one number and one character");
```

I want to check my password field allows at least **one number, one character and any number of specialcharacters/numbers/characters**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first regex is saying it can have only one character... so change it to

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]+$/.test(value)// add + to indicate one or more instances of the set
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w7keu2tf/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("pwcheck", function(value) {
   return /^[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_]+$/.test(value)&& /[a-z]/.test(value) 
   && /\d/.test(value) ;
}, "password must contain atleast one number and one character");
```